# deploying bot to heroku, can't push bot to heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

I'm having issues deploying my bot i made using discord.py into discord using heroku. I've followed many guides and looked into mane other sources as well to why it is happening and nothing seems to be working. This is what i get....

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/tony1bally/education-helper (from -r /tmp/build_e8b937d57bb9efdeafd512bb63149ee1/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/tony1bally/education-helper to /tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/tony1bally/education-helper /tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc/pip-egg-info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc/
remote:            Complete output (5 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
remote:                buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
remote:            FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-7hfbm1vc/setup.py'
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to education-helper.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/education-helper.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/education-helper.git'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
This is through the command prompt btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared https://github.com/tony1bally/education-helper as a dependency in `requirements.txt` but the repository is empty and cannot be installed with `pip` as a Python module.

Remove it from `requirements.txt`, add, commit and push again.

Comment: even after removing it from my requirements.txt, I still get the same issue. Nothing has changed

Comment: Removed? added the file to git? committed? pushed?